# How to declare constants in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am really new to Solidity and smart contracts and would really appreciate some help. I am following a tutorial and this is the exact code they use. But when I compile the code I get this error:

ParserError: Expected primary expression.
    address public constant approver = ;

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract ApprovalContract {

    address public sender;
    address public receiver;
    address public constant approver = ;

    function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        sender = msg.sender;
        receiver = _receiver;
    }

    function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
        return(approver);
    }

    function approve() external {
        require(msg.sender == approver);
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant needs to be initialized

```
address public constant approver = YOURADDRESS;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of constant variables in Solidity:

- Constants: a variable that is hardcoded in the smart contract and that you cannot change the value
- Immutables: variables you can only define the value in the constructor and that cannot be updated afterwards

Here is an example:

```
uint256 public constant EXAMPLE_NUMBER = 123;

unit256 public immutable EXAMPLE_NUMBER_2;

constructor(uint256 _number) {
    EXAMPLE_NUMBER_2 = _number;
}
```